Auth beans from custom-security-spring-boot-starter are not applied to application
I am making custom-security-spring-boot-starter.
A problem is that my auth beans are not used by application. Looks like are used just dependency spring-boot-starter-security with default auth beans.
In starter dependencies I just use:
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"

I use spring-boot 2.7 and I have set up META-INF/spring.factories:
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=rest.auth.configuration.WebFluxSecurityConfiguration,rest.auth.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration

In my starter I have overrided auth beans:
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
class WebFluxSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(
        userDetails: UserDetails,
    ): ReactiveUserDetailsService {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(
        http: ServerHttpSecurity,
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        ...
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.SERVLET)
class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(
        userDetails: UserDetails,
    ): UserDetailsService {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(
        http: HttpSecurity,
    ): SecurityFilterChain {
        ...
    }
}


But these beans are not applied to application and use default auth beans.

Beans are present in applicationContext. @AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) - doest't help

Before that I added @AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) over every bean, but I should just over configuration class.
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
class WebFluxSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(
        userDetails: UserDetails,
    ): ReactiveUserDetailsService {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(
        http: ServerHttpSecurity,
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        ...
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.SERVLET)
class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(
        userDetails: UserDetails,
    ): UserDetailsService {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(
        http: HttpSecurity,
    ): SecurityFilterChain {
        ...
    }
}

